# JDK/JRE to Chose for I.Mx6(ARM)

Tags: java

What is difference Between the two different ARM JDK's which is given in Oracle website?

1. JAVA SE &
2. JAVA Embedded SE

[JAVA SE DEVELOPMENT KIT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

[image: JAVA SE DEVELOPMENT KIT]

[JAVA SE EMBEDDED](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-se/downloads/javase-embedded-downloads-2209751.html)

[image: JAVA SE EMBEDDED]

I have developed my application in Ubuntu x86 machine. (Development environment)

so, if I use ARM(i.mx6) as my Target,  then which version of JDK/JRE to be installed in that TARGET.

Why Oracle has given these two variants. Which variant i have to use for my Target ARM (I.mx6), so that it Supports JAVA FX GUI?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the notes at the bottom of the table, you will see the difference :

First link, ARMv5/ARMv6/ARMv7 Linux - SoftFP ABI, Little Endian 2, is noted (2)

> (2)  gcc options used include:  -msoft-float

Second link, ARM v6/v7 Linux - VFP, HardFP ABI, Little Endian 1  is noted (1)

> (1) gcc options used include:  -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp

Option (1) is for using hardware floating point support and option (2) is for using software floating point support. Read the gcc documentation for more information.